# How to set all column attribute "UpdateCheck" quickly for all tables?

Tags: linq-to-sql, database

i need to set LINQ UpdateCheck attribute of columns in every tables in mine db, is there any quick way to set all column's updatecheck attribute?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do either. The problem that forces me to this operation is that I can't get the updated properties when using Entity.GetChangeSet() method. But I think this is not a good idea ):

Answer (score 2):

There's no such feature built into the L2S designer in Visual Studio, but you can either:

**a)** Add a timestamp/rowversion column to all tables; the timestamp column will then be used for concurrency checks instead of all columns. (...if the reason you want to do this is to simplify the SQL update statements...)

...or...

**b)** open the DBML file in an xml editor and do search/replace or other mass update.

...or...

**c)** try out my add-in for L2S ( you can download it and get a trial license from [www.huagati.com/dbmltools](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/) ); one of the commands it adds to the L2S designer is a "mass update" for the updatecheck property:

[alt text http://forum.huagati.com/upload/2/dbmlToolsMenu_v189.png](http://forum.huagati.com/upload/2/dbmlToolsMenu_v189.png)

[alt text http://forum.huagati.com/upload/2/concurrencyModeOptions.png](http://forum.huagati.com/upload/2/concurrencyModeOptions.png)

Answer (score 0):

There's one way you could do this in code. If you iterate over each of the tables properties and obtain their ColumnAttributes, you can set each of their UpdateCheck properties to Never. This has to be done prior to the mapping source being created for the DataContext, though.

It's good for quickly testing something, but it's probably not the best idea for updating the ColumnAttributes on each of your properties.